# Python multiprocess lists of images

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to use multi process to stack many images. Each stack consists of 5 images, which means I have a list of images with a sublist of the images which should be combined:

> img_lst = [[01_A, 01_B, 01_C, 01_D, 01_E], [02_A, 02_B, 02_C, 02_D, 02_E], [03_A, 03_B, 03_C, 03_D, 03_E]]

At them moment I call my function do_stacking(sub_lst) with a loop:

```
for sub_lst in img_lst:
    # example: do_stacking([01_A, 01_B, 01_C, 01_D, 01_E])
    do_stacking(sub_lst)
```

I want to speed up with multiprocessing but I am not sure how to call pool.map function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    # I store my lists in a file
    f_in = open(stacking_path + "stacks.txt", 'r') 
    f_stack = f_in.readlines()

    for data in f_stack:
        data = data.strip()
        data = data.split('\t')
        # data is now my sub_lst

    # Not sure what to do here, set the sublist, f_stack?
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(do_stacking, ???)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**Edit**:

I have a list of list:

[

[01_A, 01_B, 01_C, 01_D, 01_E],

[02_A, 02_B, 02_C, 02_D, 02_E],

[03_A, 03_B, 03_C, 03_D, 03_E]

]

Each sublist should be passed to a function called do_stacking(sublist). I only want to proceed with the sublist and not with the entire list.

My question is how to handle the loop of the list (for x in img_lst)? Should I create a loop for each Pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pool.map` works like the builtin `map` function.It fetch one element from the second argument each time and pass it to the function that represent by the first argument.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    # I store my lists in a file
    f_in = open(stacking_path + "stacks.txt", 'r') 
    f_stack = f_in.readlines()
    img_list = []
    for data in f_stack:
        data = data.strip()
        data = data.split('\t')
        # data is now my sub_lst
        img_list.append(data)
        print img_list # check if the img_list is right?

    # Not sure what to do here, set the sublist, f_stack?
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(do_stacking, img_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: But then do_stacking will proceed only one of the sub_lst (the last one in img_list).

Comment: @snowflake I think there maybe something wrong in `img_list` which is built in the for loop(check it in your environment because I don't know the content of stacks.txt).I just run the code fine.

Comment: I think I did not explain very good what I want to do, I edited my post above. If I implement your solution do_stacking will only take care for the last sub-list of img_lst.

Comment: @snowflake, I know what you want to do, you should print the `img_list` and print the sub_lst in `do_stacking` to check if the data is ok. the right way to use pool.map is which my answer has shown.

Comment: Where should the loop for sub_lst in img_lst: go? If I put the loop in do_Stacking() I get no speed improvement.

Comment: @snowflake   pool.map(do_stacking, img_list) can do it as expected. You said do_stacking just proceed only the last one in `img_list` which is weird, so you need to check if the  `img_list` is really what you thought it was.